# Adjusting tick label size on twin axes

Tags: matplotlib, axes

I'm having trouble changing the tick label properties on a plot with twin axes. I want the text to be small and in a different font than the default. I found a way that worked fine until I tried using twiny(). The second axes doesn't respond to the tick-formatting instructions, as you can see on the figure. Am I missing something crucial or is there a bug in matplotlib?

Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.3, matplotlib 1.1.1rc

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from matplotlib import pyplot as p
from numpy import sin, cos, arange

x = arange(0, 10, .01)

for plotnum in range(1,5):
    p.subplot(2, 2, plotnum)
    ax1 = p.gca()
    p.plot(sin(x),x)
    ax2 = p.twiny()
    p.plot(cos(x)+plotnum,x, 'g--')

    # Set size all tick labels
    # Works for first axes (lower x-ticks) and can also change font
    for tickset in [ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks()]:
        [(tick.label.set_fontsize(plotnum*4), tick.label.set_fontname('ubuntu mono')) for tick in tickset]

    # Does not work for second axes (upper x-ticks)
    for tickset in [ax2.xaxis.get_major_ticks()]:
        [(tick.label.set_fontsize(plotnum*2), tick.label.set_fontname('ubuntu mono')) for tick in tickset]

    # This works, but doesn't allow changing font
    #ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=plotnum*2)
```

Here is an image:

[image: Here the image is]

***Edit:*** fixed incorrect indenting of tick-changing lines

***Edit:*** Inserted image (Thriveth)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ticks can have two labels (`label1` and `label2`), according to the Tick class documentation:

- 1 refers to the bottom of the plot for xticks and the left for yticks
- 2 refers to the top of the plot for xticks and the right for yticks

The `label` attribute always refers to `label1`.

You can fix your script by changing the ax2 lines to:

```
for tickset in [ax2.xaxis.get_major_ticks()]:
    [(tick.label2.set_fontsize(plotnum*2), tick.label2.set_fontname('ubuntu mono'))
```

The `get_majorticklabels` functions will work out if you 'll need `label1` or `label2` and simplifies your script:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as p
from numpy import sin, cos, arange

x = arange(0, 10, .01)

for plotnum in range(1,5):
    p.subplot(2, 2, plotnum)
    ax1 = p.gca()
    p.plot(sin(x),x)
    ax2 = p.twiny()
    p.plot(cos(x)+plotnum,x, 'g--')
    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(plotnum * 4)
        label.set_fontname('courier')
    for label in ax2.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(plotnum * 4)
        label.set_fontname('verdana')
```

Note, I put the label change routines in the loop!
[image: plotted tick labels]